# ¿Cómo implementar la animación de tipo scale a un botón y que retorne a la misma velocidad en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, animación

Quisiera saber como puedo hacer para que se ejecute una animación a un botón de tipo scale y pueda volver a su tamaño original pero conservando la velocidad de la animación (que esta dada por la duración de la misma). Esto ultimo lo aclaro porque lo que puedo hacer es que un botón agrande su tamaño a una determinada velocidad pero al momento de volver a su tamaño original lo hace en otra velocidad y yo quiero que sea la misma. El código que yo tengo es el siguiente:

**En mi clase Java**

```
Animation animationScale = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.scale);
boton.startAnimation(animationScale);
```

**En mi archivo Scale** (Dentro mi carpeta anim)

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="0.0"
        android:toXScale="1.5"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:toYScale="1.5"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="2000">
    </scale>
</set>
```

Lo que haría este código sería aumentar de tamaño mi botón a un 1.5 con una duración de 2000, pero al momento de volver a su tamaño original lo hace de una manera muy espontanea.

¿Existe alguna forma de indicarle que vuelva a su tamaño original a la misma velocidad con este tipo de animación?

Comment: ¿"Muy espontanea" te refieres a que varía el tiempo?

Comment: Me refiero a que cuando el botón llega al tamaño que le especifico (1.5 en mi ejemplo) y tiene que volver a su tamaño original, (1.0) lo hace con una velocidad mas rápida a la que lo hace al principio desde que aparece hasta que se agranda hasta el valor especificado (1.5). Esto hace que no quede bien estéticamente cuando el usuario visualiza la animación del botón.

Comment: Ok , yo tuve el mismo problema tratando de realizar la animación desde el .xml usa  android:repeatMode="reverse" , revisa la respuesta @Lucas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que así se puede conseguir la animación que quieres obtener

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:ordering="sequentially"
    >

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="0.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="1000">
    </scale>

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.5"
        android:toYScale="1.5"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:repeatCount="1"
        >
    </scale>
</set>
```

Lo que he hecho es "dividir" la animación en 2 fases, una tras de otra con `sequentially`

- 1º fase: Escalado de 0.0 a 1.0
- 2º fase: Escalado de 1.0 a 1.5. Esta 2º fase con repetición en modo inverso, para que al terminar la animación quede en escala original 1.0

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso era lo que estaba buscando :D

Answer (score 0):

Usa [android:repeatMode="reverse"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation#attr_android:repeatMode) de esta forma la misma animación se realiza nuevamente hacia atrás con el mismo tiempo con el cual inicio y termino.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="0.0"
        android:toXScale="1.5"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:toYScale="1.5"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:duration="2000">
    </scale>
</set>
```

Puedes usar también [android:repeatCount](http://android:repeatCount) para configurar el número de veces que deseas la animación sea repetida.

Comment: Esa propiedad no la conocía pero de igual manera no soluciona mi problema porque al especificarle la propiedad `android:repeatMode="reverse"` y `android:repeatCount="2"` , mi botón de ir de 0.0 a 1.5, vuelve de 1.5 a 0.0 y luego de manera abrupta va su tamaño original (1.0); y lo que estoy necesitando es que realice toda la animación a la misma velocidad de 0.0 a 1.5 y luego de 1.5 a 1.0. Espero haber sido claro. Saludos.